# The service type provided could not be loaded as a service because it does not have a default (parameter-less) constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I tried to right click my wcf svc and click on view in browser, but i have this error

[image]

This is my solution explorer and property window

[image: Solution Explorer]

Please what do I do.

Comment: It explains in the error message. Your service must have a default constructor.

Comment: Please how do I make my service to have a default constructor. I am new to WCF

Comment: Type ctor + TAB TAB